How to add border and corner radius to selected range of text using attributes in NSAttributedString?
In my code I simply have:
    let adminName = "  ADMIN  "
    let name = [adminName, "Greg Weg"].joined(separator: "  ")
    let attributed = NSMutableAttributedString(string: name)
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.minimumLineHeight = 28
    let adminAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
        .foregroundColor: UIColor.purple,
        .backgroundColor: UIColor.purple.withAlphaComponent(0.2),
        .paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle,
        .font: UIFont.poppinsRegular.withSize(16),
    ]
    let adminRange = attributed.mutableString.range(of: adminName)
    attributed.setAttributes(adminAttributes, range: adminRange)

    //assign attributed to UILabel

but the effect is following:

What do I need to have?


Unfortunately, to get this level of control, you're going to need to dive pretty deep into the text system: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504031/control-spacing-around-custom-text-attributes-in-nslayoutmanager/76972937#76972937

For your use-case, instead of having that text as part of an attributed string, could you put a custom view next to a label instead? You'll save yourself a lot of headache.

Unfortunately not. that element (userName) is a part of third party library that needs NSAttributedString there‍♂️ I need to display (or not) admin label next to user name‍♂️

Ah — so presumably, you can't control the drawing of the attributed string either... You may need to compromise on the design then, given limited control, unfortunately.

"Compromise on the design" - it sounds like a solution. Thank you.

A bit dirty and fast solution:
class Lbl: UILabel {
    var selectedRange: NSRange? {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    let textLayer = CATextLayer()

    let selectedLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        layer.masksToBounds = false
        let selectedColor = UIColor.purple

        textLayer.string = attributedText
        if let selectedRange {
            let mutable = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attributedText ?? NSAttributedString(string: text ?? ""))
            mutable.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: selectedColor, range: selectedRange)
            textLayer.string = mutable
        }
        textLayer.contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale
        textLayer.foregroundColor = textColor.cgColor
        textLayer.bounds = attributedText?.boundingRect(with: rect.insetBy(dx: -5, dy: -5).size,
                                                        options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading],
                                                        context: nil) ?? rect
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        textLayer.render(in: context!)
        guard let selectedRange, let rangeRect = boundingRectForCharacterRange(range: selectedRange) else { return }

        selectedLayer.borderWidth = 1
        selectedLayer.borderColor = selectedColor.cgColor
        selectedLayer.fillColor = selectedColor.withAlphaComponent(0.2).cgColor
        selectedLayer.bounds = rangeRect
        selectedLayer.cornerRadius = 4
        selectedLayer.masksToBounds = true
        selectedLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rangeRect.insetBy(dx: -2, dy: -2), cornerRadius: 4).cgPath
        selectedLayer.render(in: context!)
    }
}

extension UILabel {
    func boundingRectForCharacterRange(range: NSRange) -> CGRect? {
        guard let attributedText = attributedText else { return nil }
        setNeedsLayout()
        layoutIfNeeded()
        let textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: attributedText)
        let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
        let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: intrinsicContentSize)
        var glyphRange = NSRange()

        textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)
        textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0
        layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)

        layoutManager.characterRange(forGlyphRange: range, actualGlyphRange: &glyphRange)

        return layoutManager.boundingRect(forGlyphRange: glyphRange, in: textContainer)
    }
}


Usage:
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: Lbl!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        foo()
    }

    func foo() {
        let adminName = "  ADMIN  "
        let name = [adminName, "Greg Weg"].joined(separator: "  ")
        let attributed = NSMutableAttributedString(string: name, attributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)])
        let adminRange = attributed.mutableString.range(of: adminName)
        label.attributedText = attributed
        label.selectedRange = adminRange
    }
}

Result:


Yes, it is dirty and will not work;) There is no access to UILaleb property at all;) If I have an access to UILabel there are much more simpler and faster solutions;)

UILabel has only a few usable properties, and you can override them and forward to the underlying layer, if not too lazy ;)
